# Retrieve data from field which stores XML and datatype is CLOB

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I want to retrieve the XML value stored in PKDATA data field where name is inpatienttype want returns value 262784091 as inpatienttype

OUTPUT

| A | B | Inpatientype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11,212 | 2587165 | 262784091 |

Dataset
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCjhD.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:DataSet xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/t/cn/el">
    <EnumObject>
        <name>InpatientType</name>
        <prompt>InpatientType</prompt>
        <value>262784091</value>
        <radiobutton>false</radiobutton>
    </EnumObject>
    <StringObject>
        <name>xxx</name>
        <prompt></prompt>
        <value>/widget.jsp</value>
        <width>99</width>
    </StringObject>
</ns2:DataSet>
```

I used the following queries but didn't work

```
SELECT XMLQUERY(
  '/EnumObject/name'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(e.pkdata)
  RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS name
FROM EXTDATA as e
```

---

```
select x.*
from [dbo].[EXTRADATA] rt
cross join xmltable(
  '/EnumObject/name'
  passing xmltype(rt.packeddata)
  columns name number path 'name/@value'
) x
```

Getting this error

> Parse error at line: 3, column: 3: Incorrect syntax near 'PASSING'.

Can someone please help me here

Comment: Your question seems to use Oracle syntax (see: [XMLQUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions224.htm)), but the tag below your question says `sql-server` (which is Microsoft SQL server).   Can you lease [edit] the question, and provide the correct info ?

Comment: Sorry Lukk i m new to SQL, was using SAS but now changing to SQL server Management Studio

Comment: Different SQL databases have different syntax. Especially when getting info from an XML.  You currently use XMLQUERY, which is not valid in `MS SQL Server`. (and `SQL server Management Studio` is just some client which is used to connect to `MS SQL Server`)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Thanks, the vesrion is Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.16003.0 Apr 28 2021 04:55:16 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. XML datatype is varachar(MAX) therefore i have tried using following query but gives me the error Msg 104220, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 Cannot find data type 'xml'. SELECT a,b,(pkdata).value('(/EnumObject/name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') FROM [dbo].tocextradata CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(packeddata AS xml)) AS x(pkdata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can use XQuery via the [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type), [query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type) and [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) functions.

If the source data involves custom XML namespaces you can also use [with xmlnamespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces) to namespace qualify the nodes of your XQuery, for example:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://www.test.com/t/cn/el' as cnel
)
select
  EnumObject.value('(./name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as name,
  EnumObject.value('(./prompt/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as prompt,
  EnumObject.value('(./value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as value
from dbo.TOCEXTRADATA
cross apply packeddata.nodes('/cnel:DataSet/EnumObject') p(EnumObject);
```

| name | prompt | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| InpatientType | InpatientType | 262784091 |

The following query avoids the custom namespace on the root node and returns an equivalent result:

```sql
select
  EnumObject.value('(./name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as name,
  EnumObject.value('(./prompt/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as prompt,
  EnumObject.value('(./value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as value
from dbo.TOCEXTRADATA
cross apply packeddata.nodes('//EnumObject') p(EnumObject);
```

| name | prompt | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| InpatientType | InpatientType | 262784091 |

---

**Edit:** when the data type of the `packeddata` column isn't `xml` you'll need to cast it to the correct type. The two example queries above need to be modified in the following way:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://www.test.com/t/cn/el' as cnel
)
select
  EnumObject.value('(./name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as name,
  EnumObject.value('(./prompt/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as prompt,
  EnumObject.value('(./value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as value
from dbo.TOCEXTRADATA
outer apply ( select cast(packeddata as xml) as xmlData ) oa
cross apply xmlData.nodes('/cnel:DataSet/EnumObject') p(EnumObject);
```

```sql
select
  EnumObject.value('(./name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as name,
  EnumObject.value('(./prompt/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as prompt,
  EnumObject.value('(./value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as value
from dbo.TOCEXTRADATA
outer apply ( select cast(packeddata as xml) as xmlData ) oa
cross apply xmlData.nodes('//EnumObject') p(EnumObject);
```

Comment: Thanks i get the following error when I use the above code The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml. i tried to use the  following but get incorrect syntax near passing  select x.*
from [dbo].[EXTRADATA] rt
cross join xmltable(
  '/EnumObject/name'
  passing xmltype(rt.packeddata)
  columns name number path 'name/@value'
) x

Comment: @user2703679 Your question suggests that you're using the `xml` data type. What is the actual data type of the `packeddata` column in your table?

Comment: CLOB i have added screenshot.  We use another tool sql tool in old world that supports the following syntax extractvalue(xmltype(packeddata),'//EnumObject[name=''InpatientType'']/value')  but remediating it to SQL server(new world) this is not working.

Comment: `clob` is not a data type in Microsoft SQL Server, though `single_blob`, `single_clob` and `single_nclob` are options to [openrowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql). Is it possible that the data type of your `packeddata` column is `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` instead of `xml`?

Comment: yes i checked it, and its varchar(max), then how the query will be i tried out the following

Comment: Well, as the error message says, those functions only work on the `xml` data type. I will update my answer to include a type 
cast for you.

Comment: Thanks i have tried using following query but gives me the error Msg 104220, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Cannot find data type 'xml'. SELECT a,b,(pkdata).value('(/EnumObject/name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM [dbo].tocextradata
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(packeddata AS xml)) AS x(pkdata)

Comment: Are you sure you're executing this in a Microsoft SQL Server? `xml` has been a data type there since at least SQL Server 2005.

Comment: SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;) vesrion is Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.16003.0 Apr 28 2021 04:55:16 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. About the tool is follows                                                                                                 SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18330.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.100.37971.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.19040.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0